# Why do java.util.Calendar before() and after() methods take an Object as an argument, and simply return false if the passed Object is not a Calendar?

Tags: java, calendar, java.util.date

This was a bit of a WTF moment for me...
I know the Java Date/Calendar classes are supposed to be horrible, but still why do this?

This just makes it easy to introduce subtle bugs, or am I missing something?

Comment: This allows you to see if a `Date` is before a `Calendar`. Which is just horrible.

Comment: @Kayaman Not according to the Javadoc: _if and only if when is a Calendar instance. Otherwise, the method returns false._

Comment: The Javadoc isn't exactly clear (you missed out on the part before "if and only if"). Of course it could be left as a possibility for subclasses to provide the functionality I described.

Comment: @Kayaman Not sure what you mean - the code of `before` is `return when instanceof Calendar && compareTo((Calendar)when) < 0;` so it definitely returns false for a non Calendar Object, such as a Date for example.

Comment: True. So it could be left as a possibility for subclasses to allow comparing different classes of objects.

Comment: @Kayaman Although that would break the contract of the base Calendar class...

Answer (score 3):

I believe the original reason was that the methods were meant to be 'compatible' with the compareTo() method on the Comparable interface which specifies an Object argument (although this was obviously improved with the introduction of the generics syntax). Essentially before() is the same as compareTo(..) < 0 - and uses this to actually do the comparison internally.

Basically, it's a bad legacy thing though. Hopefully we can all move to the Java 8 libraries now and pretend Calendar never existed.